# Data connection get dropped when receive a voice call when its 4G

Tags: java, android, 4g

I'm developing a android mobile app and there is a situation when app send a request to server (web service call) . System generate a voice call to obtain some information (dial pad key inputs) . And server pick that key inputs and process further finally send the response to APP. App is waiting for the response of web service call and display the response to user.

My problem is when mobile is in 4G and once receive call in to that same device connection is switching from 4g to 3G and connection get dropped. Because of that App is unable to display correct response to user.

So is there any solution available for that issue so that app's request connection not get dropped though it change from 4G to 3G when receive a voice call.

Comment: So, does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are experiencing is CSFB (Circuit-switched Fallback). This occurs when a CS voice call attempt is made on an LTE device. Since LTE is packet-switched only, the network must have the device fallback to a CS compatible technology, such as WCDMA (3G).

If you have a VoLTE compatible device, then it would stay on 4G and this fallback scenario would not occur.